# How to configure SQL Native Client with powershell?

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I have been tasked to write a script that will enable tcp and named pipes protocols for SQL Server 2008 Express R2 instance.  I have found out how to enable these protocols for the SQL Server instance itself, but I haven't found any way to control the SQL Native Client from powershell.

My script is part of an installer, and the code I am installing expects these protocols to be enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.  The protocols can be enabled by setting a registry key:

in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\SNI10.0`, set the `ProtocolOrder` key to contain the protocols that should be enabled:

```
sm = Shared memory
np = Named pipes
tcp = TCP (he)
via = Via
```

Protocols not listed in this key will be disabled.

Answer (score 5):

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")
$wmi = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer") "$env:computername"
$wmi.ServerInstances["SQLEXPRESS"].ServerProtocols["Tcp"].IsEnabled = $true
$wmi.ServerInstances["SQLEXPRESS"].ServerProtocols["Np"].IsEnabled = $true
$wmi.ClientProtocols["tcp"].IsEnabled = $true
$wmi.ClientProtocols["np"].IsEnabled = $true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I already have a script that performs this part of the operation.  I need to enable the same protocols on the SQL Native Client.

Comment: I believe that's under ClientProtocols. I edited the code and added setting clientprotocols.

Comment: Good one. The only thing needed in addition is a call to `Alter()` after changing the configuration.