# How to use a scripting language to change settings in MMC Snapin

Tags: powershell, automation, mmc

I've been building a script to setup a MSSQL server in PowerShell, but I'm stuck at this point. I can't figure out where the SQL Server Configuration Manager SnapIn is saving the data and I can't figure out how to access it via COM.

Is there a way to change MMC settings (command-line) without having to click through the GUI?

Comment: What MCC? what settings?

Comment: SQL Server Configuration Manager. I want to change settings in "SQL Server Network Configuration"/"Protocols for MSSQLSERVER"/"TCP/IP"/"IP Addresses": IP1.TCP Port, IP.Enabled, and IPAll.TCP Port

Comment: You can use SMO, or edit the registry entries. See examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033773/how-to-configure-sql-native-client-with-powershell

Comment: That did solve it for me. However, I also found a way to create an MMC COM object (`MMC20.Application`). Also, thanks a ton for that link :D That was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the settings you change in SQL Server are stored in SQL Server somewhere, which means TSQL is used to make those changes.  My favorite trick is to **run SQL Profiler against a database while changing its settings**.  You can then see the SQL being used to modify the settings you need, which you can execute from your script.  Very useful